# FFMPEG - Watermark video with same quality and filesize

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have some videos, and I'd like to watermark them with a transparent PNG. Here's what I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -i 9.flv -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark];[in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" 9_w.flv
```

However, bitrate or quality is not preserved. Preferably I'd like ffmpeg to re-encode the file with exactly the same settings as the original file (same codecs, bitrate). If thats not easily possible, I'd like to encode with a specific codec, but preserving 'quality', however that is measured.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
ffmpeg -i 9.flv -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark];[in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" -vcodec flv -sameq 9_w.flv
```

this tells ffmpeg to use the same quality for video encoding.

you can also add

```
-acodec libmp3lame copy
```

before the output to do the same with the audio encoding.

Comment: Sameq means same quantiser, not same quality. This isn't what I'm looking for.